# Using C# System..Numerics.Vector<T> to unpack / pack bits

Tags: c#, vector, bitwise-operators, simd, system.numerics

I’m testing the capabilities of the .Net C# System.Numerics.Vector class for packing and unpacking bits.

I was hoping for Vector bitwise shift left/right functionality but that is not currently available so I tried to simulate shifting using arithmetic & logical methods as below. Here’s what I saw:

Packing (a simulated bitwise SHIFT LEFT and OR) using Vector.Multiply() and Vector.BitwiseOr() is slightly worse* than array/pointer code.

*<10% degradation in throughput (MB/sec).

But Unpacking (a simulated bitwise SHIFT RIGHT and AND) using Vector.Divide() and Vector.BitwiseAnd() is far worse** than array/pointer code.

**50% degradation in throughput

NB:

- Vector was tested using unit  (this was also raised in comments).
- Test basis was the packing & unpacking of 100Mn up to 1Bn integers in blocks of 65536 integers. I randomly generated the int[] for each block.
- I also tested bitwise (& | >> <<) as well as arithmetic (+ - * /) operations and saw no marked difference in cost. Even divide was not that bad with only a 10% degradation in throughout vs multiply (the question of  division was raised in comments)
- I changed my original test code (for the non-Vector comparison) to an unsafe/pointer routine to create more of a like-for-like test in terms of packing (many integers to a word) versus unpacking (a word to many integers). This brought the difference in throughout  (between packing & unpacking) for the non-Vector code down to a variance of <5%. (which counters my comment about the compiler and optimization below)
- Non-Optimized Vector: packing is 2x as fast as unpacking
- Optimized Vector:  yielded a 4x improvement (versus non-optimized Vector) in packing and a 2x improvement for unpacking
- Non-Optimized array/pointer: unpacking is ~5% faster than packing
- Optimized array/pointer: yielded a 3x improvement (versus non-optimized array pointer) for packing and a 2.5x improvement for unpacking. Overall,  Optimized array/pointer packing was <5% faster than Optimized array/pointer unpacking.
- Optimized array/pointer packing was ~10% faster than an Optimized  Vector pack

Conclusion so far:

- Vector.Divide() appears to be a comparatively slower implementation vs a normal arithmetic division
- Furthermore, the Compiler does not appear to optimize Vector.Divide() code to anywhere near the same extent as Vector.Multiply()  (which supports comments below regarding the optimising of division)
- Array/pointer processing is at present slightly faster than the Vector class for packing data and significantly faster for unpacking
- System.Numerics needs Vector.ShiftLeft() & Vector.ShiftRight() methods

Question (updated);

- is my conclusion roughly on track? or are there other aspects to check/consider?

Further Information:

```
int numPages =  8192; // up to >15K     
int testSize = 65536;
StopWatch swPack = new StopWatch();
StopWatch swUnpack = new StopWatch();
long byteCount = 0;
for (int p = 0; p < numpages; b++)
{
    int[] data = GetRandomIntegers(testSize, 14600, 14800);

    swPack.Start();
    byte[] compressedBytes = pack(data);
    swPack.Stop();

    swUnpack.Start();
    int[] unpackedInts = unpack(compressedBytes);
    swUnpack.Stop();

    byteCount += (data.Length*4);

}
Console.WriteLine("Packing Throughput (MB/sec): " + byteCount / 1000 / swPack.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.WriteLine("Unpacking Throughput (MB/sec): " + byteCount / 1000 / swUnpacking.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Unlike shifting left for multiplication, shifting right for division only works correctly for *unsigned* integers. If you are using signed integers then the compiler can not safely optimise division using shifts.

Comment: @PaulR: Well you can, it just takes a couple extra instructions to handle the difference in rounding between arithmetic right shift vs. signed division.  See https://godbolt.org/g/6HDjhB for gcc/clang output from `v4si div2(v4si v) {
     return v/2;
}` where v4si is a GNU C native vector of 32-bit `int`.  Code-gen for other divisors is fun; powers of 2 are still cheap, other divisors give you a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, I was thinking mainly of powers of 2, and translating directly to a single shift instruction, but yes of course there are still further optimisations to handle other divisors and division with signed values etc, although the benefit of these is not quite so dramatic.

Comment: I did use Vector<uint>. So: I double checked my tests then wondered whether there was an inherent speed difference between the bitwise operators of AND, XOR, >> and << (which didn’t make sense to me if there was).  I tested a simple >> versus << a billion times but NO real difference. Then I tested packing & unpacking without Vector<T> and I saw a similar difference, ie unpacking is considerably slower. If I switch off “Optimize Code”, then the packing:unpacking falls from 4x to 1.3x as fast - which appears to indicate that << is optimised but not >> together with &. Does this sound right?

Comment: At this point you would ideally use a profiler and/or look at the generated code to see what's going on. (I don't use C# and I have no idea what kind of tools are available in a Microsoft environment, sorry.)

Comment: Division is, as far as I can tell, *not* optimized at all by the CLR. In code that is as optimized as it's going to be, this still generated a function call to a generic "divide by some vector" method - that the right hand operand is constant is just ignored.

Comment: @Peter: Haswell has 1 per clock throughput for `psl/rd` (left/right shift), vs. 3 per clock throughput for `pand` (http://agner.org/optimize/).  Skylake can run immediate-count vector shifts on 2 ports, but still not as many as booleans.  Barrel shifters cost more than a bitwise boolean.  Were you benchmarking latency instead of throughput?  Or did you benchmark in a loop that only did one operation per iteration anyway, or bottlenecked on stores or something else? If right and left shift are different, perhaps your compiler optimized left-shift by 1 to use addition (`paddd`) instead of shift?

Comment: Benchmarking with optimization disabled is pretty much useless.  Different code will be hurt by different amounts from disabling optimization, and that doesn't tell you anything useful.  If you want to test that a microbenchmark is sane, one check is that time taken scales linearly with the repeat count.  If that's not true, you're measuring something else, or partly overhead, or your benchmark got optimized away.  The best check is to look at the machine code / assembly that actually runs and make sure it looks like the machine code from your real use-case.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I just added the testing code above. I've run the tests multiple times, with & without "Optimize Code", with the results consistent as per my posting. As far as I can see, the results point to a less than optimal implementation of Vector.Divide. Left v right shift (the non-Vector approach) times do not appear (now) to be the issue...

Comment: Doesn't C# have a `Vector.ShiftRight` or something?  Why are you messing around with Divide and Multiply by constant vectors in the first place?  And which of your benchmark numbers are still from un-optimized code?  e.g. is *Unsafe/pointer packing was anyway ~10% faster than a Vector pack* with optimization disabled?  If so, it's a useless comparison.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Vector does not have Shift Left or Shift Right methods. And comparisons are like-for-like

Comment: Comparing two things with optimization disabled for both is still useless, or at least not useful at all for figuring out which one you should use in your real program.

Answer (score 0):

**IL**

```
/// non-SIMD fallback implementation for 128-bit right-shift (unsigned)
/// n: number of bit positions to right-shift a 16-byte memory image.
/// Vector(T) argument 'v' is passed by-ref and modified in-situ.
/// Layout order of the two 64-bit quads is little-endian.

.method public static void SHR(Vector_T<uint64>& v, int32 n) aggressiveinlining
{
    ldarg v
    dup
    dup
    ldc.i4.8
    add
    ldind.i8
    ldc.i4.s 64
    ldarg n
    sub
    shl

    ldarg v
    ldind.i8
    ldarg n
    shr.un

    or
    stind.i8

    ldc.i4.8
    add
    dup
    ldind.i8
    ldarg n
    shr.un
    stind.i8

    ret
}
```

**pseudocode**

```
As<Vector<ulong>,ulong>(ref v) = (As<Vector<ulong>,ulong>(in v) >> n) | 
                                  (ByteOffsAs<Vector<ulong>,ulong>(in v, 8) << (64 - n));
ByteOffsAs<Vector<ulong>,ulong>(ref v, 8) >>= n;
```

**C# extern declaration**

```
static class vector_ext
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.ForwardRef | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    extern public static void SHR(ref Vector<ulong> v, int n);
};
```

You can link intermediate **.netmodule** binaries produced from **IL** (`ildasm.exe`) and **C#** (`csc.exe`) together into a single assembly by using the `/LTCG` (link-time code generation) option in `link.exe`.

**runtime x64  JIT result  (.NET Framework 4.7.2)**

```
0x7FF878F5C7E0    48 89 4C 24 08       mov qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx
0x7FF878F5C7E5    8B C2                mov eax,edx
0x7FF878F5C7E7    F7 D8                neg eax
0x7FF878F5C7E9    8D 48 40             lea ecx,[rax+40h]
0x7FF878F5C7EC    48 8B 44 24 08       mov rax,qword ptr [rsp+8]
0x7FF878F5C7F1    4C 8B 40 08          mov r8,qword ptr [rax+8]
0x7FF878F5C7F5    49 D3 E0             shl r8,cl
0x7FF878F5C7F8    4C 8B 08             mov r9,qword ptr [rax]
0x7FF878F5C7FB    8B CA                mov ecx,edx
0x7FF878F5C7FD    49 D3 E9             shr r9,cl
0x7FF878F5C800    4D 0B C1             or  r8,r9
0x7FF878F5C803    4C 89 00             mov qword ptr [rax],r8
0x7FF878F5C806    48 83 C0 08          add rax,8
0x7FF878F5C80A    8B CA                mov ecx,edx
0x7FF878F5C80C    48 D3 28             shr qword ptr [rax],cl
0x7FF878F5C80F    C3                   ret
```

Answer (score 0):

`Vector.Divide` has no hardware acceleration for integer types. It is very slow.

It wasn't until `.NET 7.0` that Vector added ShiftRightArithmetic, ShiftRightLogical methods.

I developed the VectorTraits library. It allows lower versions of `.NET` programs (`.NET Core 3.0`+, `.NET 5.0`+) to use the hardware accelerated ShiftRightArithmetic, ShiftRightLogical methods.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/VectorTraits